# Plotting many graphs with different and distinguishable colors

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, matlab-figure

I have this plotting loop and I want to assign different colors to that. Now it considers only the colors that it wants. So, when `N` increases, the colors of some of the graphs are the same. So distinguishing between them is really hard. How can I dedicate different colors to the different graphs?

`N=24` and is the number of the graphs.

```
for i=1:N 
    plot(time(1:350),STDX(1:350,i),'lineWidth',3) 
hold on 
end
```

Comment: I just want to have different colors in the graph, the perception is important.
The information can be extracted by their matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define some example values, since you haven't provided any:

```
N = 24;
time = linspace(0, 5, 350).';
STDX = cos(bsxfun(@times, time, linspace(0, 1, N))); % example values
```

In recent Matlab versions, you only need to **set the `'ColorOrder'` property of the axis** as desired, and then plot normally:

```
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', parula(24)) % set ColorOrder property of the axis
hold on 
for ii = 1:N 
    plot(time(1:350), STDX(1:350, ii), 'lineWidth', 3) 
end
```

Note also that you can **get rid of the loop** and just use

```
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', parula(24)) % set ColorOrder property of the axis
hold on
plot(time, STDX, 'lineWidth', 3)
```

which automatically plots each column of `STDX` with a different color. This still requires `hold on` so that the call to `plot` doesn't reset the `'ColorOrder'` property.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make a cell array of the colors you want and then set the plot color inside your loop with those colors. Here is an example:

```
C = {'k','b','r','g','y',[.5 .6 .7],[.8 .2 .6]}; % Cell array of colors
figure;
x = 0:.01:1;
hold on
for i=1:7
   plot(x,x.^i,'color',C{i});
end
```

Example output:
[image]

Comment: Not that it really matters, but probably your code is actually using `plot(x,x.^i,'.-','color',C{i});`